# Why is search automatically converted to tags?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, search

On meta, I just did the search:

```
flags design bug
```

Which gets automatically converted to:

```
[flags] [design] [bug]
```

and thus returns no results.

Why is this converted?

I've tried to replicate, and seemed to find that strings are converted to tags if all strings are a tag, and each tag has >X number of questions - but surely if the combined search gives no results, it should fall back to searching for the strings instead? (Where there [**are** results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22flags%22%22design%22%22bug%22).)

Comment: Seems that using quotes works around this if you don't want them to be converted: ["flags" "design" "bug"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22flags%22+%22design%22+%22bug%22)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any time one of the words matches one of the top 40 tags for that site, it will be converted to the actual tag in an attempt to improve your search results.

See this blog: [Stack Overflow Search – Now 61% Less Crappy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/)

Comment: I wonder if this should be prevented when there would be >x search results - but regardless, this is my answer, thank you.

Comment: Also worth noting, the "top n" is a setting *per site* and is set to top 60 right now for StackOverflow.com

Comment: I absolutely despise the Auto Taggify search feature!